# "Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/oauth2/token" using PayPal REST API and Python SDK

Tags: python, rest, paypal

I'm trying to use the PayPal REST API for the first time, specifically with the Python SDK (https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK), and I'm getting the following error in test mode:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.sandbox.paypal.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/oauth2/token (Caused by <class 'socket.gaierror'>: [Errno -2] Name or service not known)
```

I set up a developer test app and am using those client_id and client_secret values, and since I'm new to all of this I'm assuming I'm just missing something but I can't seem to get a successful request through.

Anyone have any ideas? Happy to provide additional information as necessary. Thanks!

Comment: can you provide the code you used, obviously x'ing out the values

Answer (score 0):

After some number of failed authentication attempts, your connections will be rate limited.

So, first stop making automated requests. Then make sure that you are using the correct client_id/secret (sandbox is different from live).

After some time (I don't know the exact time interval), try with ONE request to verify your credentials.

You might also use the [Python SDK](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK) to help form your requests.